# Get value of asp:textbox with javascript .net 4 framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I thought I heard that in .net 4 we would be able to reference asp:textbox's by id and not have to use clientid to get the value. I can't find this documented anywhere. Just wondering if anyone knows if this works and what the syntax is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to reference the ClientID but .NET 4.0 allows you to specify values for the ClientID.

There's a good overview of what was changed in regards to ClientID in ASP.NET 4.0 at:

[ASP.NET 4.0 ClientID Overview - Asp.Net QA Team](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean a new feature of ASP.NET 4.0 which allows to manage client id yourself. Please look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP_NET4_0ClientIDFeature.aspx) for more info.